# Error when running a batch file in psql (using -f but not with <)

Tags: psql

My command prompt has the following structure:

```
psql -d databasename -h hostname -p portnumber -U username -w -f batchfile\location\here
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "ï>>¿"
> LINE 1: ï>>¿
> ```

This causes the first sql query in the batch to not run.

I don't seem to have any problems when executing a batch file using <. See example below:

```
psql -d databasename -h hostname -p portnumber -U username -w < batchfile\location\here
```

I'm running postgreSQL version 8.2.15.

Is there something in the command line or the sql batch that I need when using -f? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 8.2.15. is a little too old to expect some answer I'm afraid

Comment: You most probably have a UTF-8 encoded script **with** a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which psql can't read. Save the file _without_ BOM and everything should be fine.

Comment: And upgrade to a supported version of Postgres now.

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name! Your suggestion to save without a BOM worked!